# R - Tools - Install Packages...option box not appearing

Tags: r, install.packages

I know there have been similar questions about not getting packages to install and this is often fixed by manually placing an unzipped binary in the correct folder and then installing via RStudio.  My problem is that when I click on the Tools menu and then on 'Install Packages', I get a box that pops up that states:

'Would you like to create a personal library 'file_path' to install packages into?'   Yes/No

-When I choose Yes, the box simply reappears with the same question.  When I select no: "Unable to install packages (Default library 'file_path' is not writeable"

Because this already is my workaround for not being able to get knitr and markdown to work, I'm really looking for some help here.  I'm hoping that this also fixes my inability to open up a new RMD script (after all the libraries update, it still won't open).

Thank you!

Comment: What OS are you on? What R version are you running? Is this R or RStudio? Did you install to a non-default path? Does `.libPaths()` return a path you have permissions to write to?

Comment: Windows 7, R 3.3, it's in RStudio Version 1.0.136.  I installed to my working directory.  Yes, .libPaths() does return a writeable location.  But I can't even get the window to pop up to let me try and install (because install.packages isn't working).

Comment: Did you try to install the package from the console with `install.packages`?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in the comment right above yours.